# Grey Bar In iPhone Chrome causing problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, google-chrome, material-ui

**Not sure if this is the right platform to ask this question (sorry for that).**

I'm working on a web-app using `ReactJS` (using JS and material UI) that is intend to work on mobile screens. I'm facing a problem while opening it in iPhone's (**iPhone 12**, **iPhone 13**) chrome browser.

There's a grey bar at the bottom that is causing the issue. At the bottom of the screen I have "Button" that is being hidden behind grey area (see area pointed out by green arrow in screenshot).

Not just this screen, nearly all of my screens are rendered behind it, as result most of the functionalities are not working properly.

But this problem is not coming if I open it in laptop browser with mobile screen using developer tools.

[image]

Comment: that bar is provided by the browser itself. you cannot do anything to it. that bar should disappear when you scroll down.

Comment: mobile screen in dev tool is different from the actual mobile devices. that's why both browser behave differently.

Comment: @Layhout it is not scrolling down that's the problem

Comment: i used to face this problem, but i found other approach. you might need other approach as well.

Comment: Could you tell me other approach you used?

Comment: mine was a drawer. i used to have a drawer that disables scroll for `<body>` content user open it. in the drawer, there's a button at the bottom behind this browser gray bar and user couldn't click it. the solution was to not disable scroll, so user can still scroll the `<body>` content behind the drawer and the gray bar disappears when user scroll.